# clang/g++ difference with private inheritance and using declaration

Tags: c++, inheritance, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Params { };

template <class T>
struct Base
{
    int data() const { return 42; }
};

template <template <class> class D, class P>
struct Middle : private D<P> // must be 'public' for g++
{
};

struct Final : public Middle<Base,Params>
{
    using Base<Params>::data;
};


int main() {

    Final f;

    std::cout << f.data() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiled successfully and prints `42` with [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca52b1d443c2dce7) and gives me compile time error on [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43f91d740574931d)

> 'int Base::data() const [with T = Params]' is inaccessible

Which implementation is more complies to C++ Standard in this case?

Comment: `Final` shouldn't see `Base` at all, so I think gcc wins here?  I'm wary of my answer though, because I have a preference for clang when it comes to compliance...

Comment: @Aggieboy `Final` sees `Base`. Accessability != Visibility.

Comment: After adding `using D<P>::data;` to Middle class code compiles well on g++ : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/269f221d5a8efab8

Comment: @alexolut Right, because now `data` is `public` in `Middle`, which makes it accessable to `Final`.

Comment: @Columbo  Yeah yeah semantics.  Necessary, but annoying XD.

Comment: Just wondering, is the template stuff necessary or does the same happen if you spell out the according types?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If you completely remove templates clang gives same error as g++ http://goo.gl/aH8ZyY `error: 'Base' is a private member of 'Base'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is correct. [namespace.udecl]/17:

> The access rules for inheriting constructors are specified in 12.9;
>   otherwise all instances of the name mentioned  in a *using-declaration*
>   shall be accessible. **In particular, if a derived class uses a
>   *using-declaration* to access a member of a base class, the member name
>   shall be accessible.**